# Sybase query: save output to a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, csv, output, sql

I´ve created the following script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b <<EOF!
    select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id="1234" 
    go
    quit
    EOF!
```

Running the script I got the desirable output:

```
user@system$ ./EXECUTE_DAILY_4
```

[image]

But now, how can I save this result that I see in my terminal window in a file (.csv for example)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `user@system$ ./EXECUTE_DAILY_4 > file`?

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev it works for me, how can point your answer? from a different site, I found a 2nd solution I will adapt it to my code and paste it here too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the stdout to a file (for any process and not just sybase query). This is a shell feature, and would work in any shell

```
./EXECUTE_DAILY_4 > output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > test.sql <<EOF!

isql -U databasename_dba -P password -b
select quantity, date from name_table where numer_id="1234"
go
quit
EOF!
isql test.sql >result.csv
```